# TextView is overlapped in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this ListView layout item. It includes a TextView and an ImageView. The problem is ImageView overlaps TextView. I want TextView show ellipses or marquee. How can I fix it?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:padding="10dip">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" 

        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"        
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dip" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="lots of text here lots of text here"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely happen because of **`RelativeLayout`**, whenever you have some text with large length.

To Overcome this problem you can try replacing `RelativeLayout` with LinearLayout, and have **`android:layout_weight`** Property for your `TextView` and `ImageView`

Answer (score 0):

You can set layout width and height to in dp for eg 200 dp in order to adjust the layout. By reducing size your layout can be adjust in goodf way